# Given are vectors $v_1=(-4,2), v_2=(6,-3)$. Find all $\lambda$ with which vector $e=(1,\lambda)$ can be written using vectors $v_1$and $v_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

So, what I have to do is to write $e$ like this:
$e= e_1v_1+e_2v_2$, right? If I try equation system I get 3 unknown variables, so this is not correct method to solve this problem (or so I think...).

Q: What condition must  $\lambda$ satisfy so that this expression would be valid: $e= e_1v_1+e_2v_2$?

P.S Sorry if for some of you (if not most) this problem looks trivial, but I just haven't solved one like this before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

$$
\left\langle1, -\lambda\right\rangle = e_1\left\langle-4, 2\right\rangle + e_2\left\langle6,-3\right\rangle \\
\begin{bmatrix}-4&6 \\
2 & -3\end{bmatrix} \times \begin{bmatrix} e_1 \\
e_2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\
\lambda \end{bmatrix}
$$

The left side is singular.  If it weren't there would be an infinite number of solutions of $\left\langle e_1, e_2\right\rangle$ for *every* value of $\lambda$ which we would find using the inverse of the left side.

$$
\det{\begin{bmatrix}-4&6 \\
2 & -3\end{bmatrix}} = 12 - 12 = 0
$$

Solve the first equation, then use this solution in the second:

$$
-4e_1 + 6e_2 = 1 \rightarrow e_1 = \frac{6e_2 - 1}{4} \\
2e_1  -3e_2 = \lambda \rightarrow \frac{6e_2 - 1}{2} - 3e_2 = -\frac{1}{2} = \lambda
$$

So $\lambda = -\frac{1}{2}$.